# Casting in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, casting, android-asynctask

In the `fragmentHome` i've implemented a `TaskCompleted` interface that has only one method " `onTaskComplete`" that take the result string from the `AsyncTask` and , after the implementation in the fragmentHome, put the string as text into the `TextView`.

this is the code in the asyncTask class that return me a fatal exception on casting:

```
....private Context mContext;


private TaskCompleted mCallback;

public MyAsyncTaskClass(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCallback = (TaskCompleted) context;

}....
```

and onPostExecute i do this:

```
mCallback.onTaskComplete(results);
```

I call the asynkTask this way with an onClick in the fragmentHome:

```
new MyAsyncTaskClass(myContext).execute(URI.create("http://urlthatcontainsmydata"));
```

where myContext is :

```
private FragmentHome myContext;
........public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    myContext = (FragmentHome) activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}......
```

Thanks for the help, if you need more details just ask.

Edited: Stacktrace

```
04-20 15:12:41.449  26365-26365/com.mypackage E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.mypackage.TaskCompleted
        at com.mypackage.MyAsyncTaskClass.<init>(MyWellWS.java:32)
        at com.mypackage.FragmentHome.onClick(HomeFragment.java:129)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17362)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Edited with the stacktrace

Comment: the error means that `MainActivity` is not implementing `TaskCompleted`

Comment: ok, do i have to implement the TaskCOmpleted even into the MainActivity, or is there  a way to use the fragment as context and not the activity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `Activity` does not implement the `TaskCompleted` interface.

Comment: I implement the TaskCompleted interface in the fragment. is this wrong? it's because i use the fragment to change the text in his own textview...

Comment: You are trying to cast the `Activity` to the interface, not the `Fragment `

Comment: So, i'm using the wrong "context" as myContext. is this right? how i could use the fragment context as param and not the activity one ?

Comment: The `Context ` the `Fragment` has is the one from the `Activity`; `Fragment` itself does not `extends` from `Context`

Comment: thanks , so i have to implement the taskcompleted in my mainactivity, but now i have a problem. I use the asyncClass to fetch a string from different URI in different fragments. every fragment is in the main activity. How i could tell to every fragment to do a different parsing for the string that i receive from the async in the onTaskComplete implemented into the main activity? sorry if i was not clear :/

Comment: If you are interacting with an API, I would recommend using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: thanks, i'm interacting with a REST API that return a JSON object or JSON list.

Comment: Yeah, then definitely take a look at Retrofit

Comment: So to use retrofit i have to abandon AsyncTask?

Comment: Correct. All asynchronous stuff will be done for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the double help ^_^